# Magento 2.3.5-p1 Blank page in Admin/Product

Tags: magento2

I just installed Magento 2.3.5-p1 with Sampledata and everything seems fine until I go to admin panel and view products page or category or pages etc. I get a blank page and errors in the log files. I am also unable to add new product and I see nothing but a blank as shown in the screenshots.

System.log

```
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'tracking' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as child to 'page.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.breadcrumbs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'formkey' element cannot be added as child to 'page.formkey', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.title' element cannot be added as child to 'main.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'messages' element cannot be added as child to 'page.messages', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' element cannot be added as child to 'page.main.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'legal' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_area' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_window' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' tries to reorder itself towards 'header.inner.left', but their parents are different: 'header' and ''
respectively. [] []
[2020-07-13 05:52:54] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

#### Preconditions (*)

1. Magento 2.3.5-p1
2. Mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.32-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
3. Nginx & PHP-FPM
4. Redis as cache/page_cache & session
5. Centos 7

#### Steps to reproduce (*)

1. Visit admin panel
2. Click Content
3. Click Pages

OR

1. Visit admin panel
2. Click Catalog
3. Click Product/Categories

OR

1. Visit admin panel
2. Click Catalog
3. Click Product
4. Click `Add Product`

#### Expected result (*)

1. I should be able to view the products from sample Data
2. I should be able to view the current pages I have
3. I should be able to add a new product

#### Actual result (*)

1. [Screenshot # 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mocrb.png)
2. [Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meiDj.png)

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: To enable PHP display error reporting, open the $Magento2Root/app/bootstrap. php file and un-comment the ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Consider switching to developer mode `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: @DominicXigen I am already into developer mode. After uncommenting `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` I erased cache and refreshed the page. I do not see any error on page or in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with ngx_pagespeed module, I disabled Page Speed and now it works absolutely fine without any errors.

I added following line to nginx configuration file.

> $ vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.conf
>
> pagespeed   off;

Answer (score 0):

Have you created any plugin or something recently?

Comment: no, its totally a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

**This and is copied from github and will also drop a link for the thread you can check it if you want**

Ok, guys. There is no bug here ) Really.
There are two reasons, why you all see such a logs.

Reason 1
People keep forgetting remove "before" and "after" attributes for blocks which have been moved to another parent, so those are no longer relevant. Internal ticket in progress MAGETWO-53410 and we will clean up legacy references soon.

Reason 2
As an example, let's take 
Such references mostly (if not all) reside in default.xml files (so will be applied to all pages without exclusions), while the container "sidebar.additional” is added by 2columns-left.xml layout only. So, on pages where different page layout is used, the reference will lead to nowhere, and you will see CRITICAL error logged (while it is not critical at all).

The tricky thing is that sometimes that could be a normal case and developer understands why it happens (if want to add a block to specific container to all pages on which target container available, and don’t need that block to be added to the pages where target container is not available).

Short excerpt from internal ticket description: "Stop logging such cases at all, or at least stop marking them as CRITICAL (ensure that it’s not logged in production mode). Also it will be helpful if logged message will say the URL of the page where target container is missed".

So, as you see, we still think that logging such "broken" references is a right thing to do, since some of them are really could be caused by misspells in layout files.

here is the source link you check this out:- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3507

Comment: its not about the logs, i pasted logs for reference or more data. However, the issue is with product/categories or pages (page) being blank in the admin panel as shown in the screenshots.